# Tensor networks vs. Neural networks

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, theory

What are the differences between [Tensor network theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_network_theory) vs. regular [neural networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network), where does the tensor nature come into place? After all a matrix is a rank 2 tensor.
For me as layman both look the same: Input layer, Hidden layers, output layer:

[image]

It seems that Tensor networks is something much bigger, as it comes up also in [theoretical physics](https://www.quantamagazine.org/20150428-how-quantum-pairs-stitch-space-time/).

Apparently I am missing something in the model.

Comment: The Wikipedia article on the tensor network is basically saying that ANNs came out of this theory. The theory itself is an attempt at geometrization of neurological functions. The success of neural networks showed that it, indeed, works.

Answer (score 0):

Tensor network theory comes historically first as theory / mathematical model.
Artificial Neural networks can be seen as an application of the above "borrowing" some of the concepts elaborated in such models while integrating and further elaborating.